# Cancel Autocomplete request when space is entered, and fire it only when the user stops typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I tried searching all over the Internet and found no simple answer, which I believe exists for two problems I'm having. My Jquery UI Autocomplete is below:

```
 $('#moviename').autocomplete({
            // URL is parsed by my framework
            source:"<?=URL::route('MovieAutocomplete')?>",
            minLength:2,
            dataType:"json",
            select:function(event,ui){
                // set artist id
                $('#movieid').val(ui.item.id);
                $('#moviename').prop('disabled',true);
                $('#moviedetails').prop('disabled',false);
                $('#movieclear').html('Clear');
                $('#moviehint').toggle();
            }
});
```

This code works. However, I am looking at the performance. I have two questions:

1. My controller cancels the request if it sees a blank term. However, I would like to check this condition even before the request is sent. I have played with beforeSend, but it doesn't work somehow. Can someone help me accomplish this one?
2. I would also like to fire the AJAX request only when the user stops typing, say give it a time of 500ms to wait before it can send request to the server. Is there any easy way to do this? I am guessing "`call autocomplete inside a keyup event which will be bound to the field I want`". Please help me.

It would be great if someone can look into this one for me.

Comment: what's your beforesend code look like?

Comment: Thanks, it's `function(){
var a = $.trim(<field>)
if(a.length<1) return false;
return true;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I recently have been working with the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). This is the logic I used & it works well.

```
onKeydownMethod: function(event) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= App.autocompleteMinLength)
        {
if ($(this).val().length >= YOUR_MIN_LENGTH) {        
$('selector').autocomplete({
    minLength: YOUR_MIN_LENGTH, // min number of chars before request is made.
    delay: YOUR_DELAY, // mum of miliseconds to wait before making request.
    source: function(request, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'YOUR_URL' + ANY_PARAMS,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 50000
        }).done(function(response) {
            callback(response);  // I used a callback to send data back to the parent function. Handle the response however you like here.
        }).fail(function(error) {
            switch (error.statusText)
            {
                case 'OK':
                    // handle response.
                break;
                default:
                    // handle response
                break;
             }
         });
     }
 });
}
}
```

Comment: This answered my second question, thanks. however, how do I get over with the first one? I don't see any condition to check before the request is sent

Comment: Just an idea, but could you call a function there that checked for it? if it was good - return an integer? Since "minLength" is looking for an integer.

Or, on your keyup handler, you can check for the actual length of your string - then execute the autocomplete. Just use 0 for the minlength at that point since you have already validated that (more or less).

Something like: 

    if ($(this).val().length >= YOUR_MINLENGTH) { // init   autocomplete.
}

Comment: EDIT: I updated the sample code above to help give an idea of what I'm talking about. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but the condition that's being checked is not being bound to an event, so is it still good?

Comment: Yeah, it would need to bind to the keydown event. I updated (again) sorry for dragging it out. :)